# Multiple smtp mail with with Office 365 MidSize

Tags: office365

Is anyone know if it possible to have multiple smtp address in Office 365 (exchange) for Midsize?

For example.
anders@mydomain1.com (smtp primary)
anders@mydomain2.com (secondary)
anders@mydomain3.com (decondaty)

It should be possible to mail in for any of those addresses.

Any know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 Exchange supports multi SMTP domains (Connection no.s depends on the business type ).
Each domain can be used as email address suffix. Single users can use 1 or multi SMTP domains to receive email at same time, but only one address can be used to send email for single user.

Office 365 support the addition and deletion of SMTP domains. You need to provide the ownership for adding domain and before deleting domain, you need to remove all related address from current users.
Steps for this:

```
1. verify and add the domain to Office365.

2. setup the `sendas` permission by Powershell.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add SMTP addresses you would rather use recipients>email adresses  from https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/

or Powershell:
Set-Mailbox user@domain.com -EmailAddresses @{add="user@domain2.com"}